# cannot split': bad URI(is not URI?):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, mongodb, carrierwave

I've got the following CarrierWave initializer which works fine on my Heroku/MONGOHQ/GridFS env :

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :grid_fs
  uri = URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
  config.grid_fs_database = File.basename(uri.path)
  config.grid_fs_host = uri.host unless uri.host.blank?
  config.grid_fs_port = uri.port unless uri.port.blank?
  config.grid_fs_username = uri.user unless uri.user.blank?
  config.grid_fs_password = uri.password unless uri.password.blank?
  config.grid_fs_access_url = '/gridfs'
  config.cache_dir = "uploads"
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
end
```

but, when I try to run the code locally (in developement) I get the following error:

```
`split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

here is the full stack : http://pastie.org/1630069 I tried to add require 'uri/generic' on top of initializer but doesn't works.

Does anybody know way ?
Thanks in advance
luca

Comment: Is ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] set in your dev environment? I'm guessing not.

Comment: Ok, was not setted on my local machine ;-) Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by KenB the ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] was not setted on my local machine developement environment :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/heroku/mp3upload$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 >
```

this was a branch without the initializer, so on my local machine I had to skip that. I did it like that:

```
    if ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']
      CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.storage = :grid_fs
        uri = URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
        config.grid_fs_database = File.basename(uri.path)
        config.grid_fs_host = uri.host unless uri.host.blank?
        config.grid_fs_port = uri.port unless uri.port.blank?
        config.grid_fs_username = uri.user unless uri.user.blank?
        config.grid_fs_password = uri.password unless uri.password.blank?
        config.grid_fs_access_url = '/gridfs'
        config.cache_dir = "uploads"
        config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
      end
    end
```

I think that should be a very better way to skip a Ralis 3.0.5 initializer during the boot process, conditionally to the ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] parameter value.

If you have a better way, could you please share it ?
Many thanks :-)
luca

Answer (score 1):

another solution would be to add a ".env" file in the project root and define there environment variables like:

```
MONGOHQ_URL=mongodb://someuser:somepass@paulo.mongohq.com:10040/appid
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initializer, you can do this: `URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] || 'some_other_link')` as specified in the [MongoHQ Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq)